# Python discord bot can't read messages/ print written messages

Tags: python, discord, chatbot

I just followed tutorials on YouTube but my code does not work

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'am ready")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  print(message.content)
  if message.author == client. User:
    return

  if message.content.startswith("sa"):
    await message.channel.send("as")


client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

this code for read message and print it's content from any channel

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is change

```
client = discord. Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

with

```
client = discord. Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the intents. You can list each out like this and change them depending on what you want your bot to do:

```
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
intents.presences = True
```

Or, you could use `intents = discord.Intents.all()`

Comment: Hey as a small improvment, can you describe how to get the intents object first hand.